# How to create a NSMatrix of NSImageCell in Interface Builder in 10.6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, osx-snow-leopard

How can I create a matrix (NSMatrix object) of NSImageCell cells (usually located in an NSImageView) in Interface Builder 3.2.1 (i.e. the one made for Snow Leopard?)

In the "old days", you would drag an NSImageView, and then option-drag the corner of the control. It seemed to have stopped working in 3.2.1... Is there another way? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just drag an instance of `NSImageView` into your view in IB. Select it and then choose `Layout > Embed Objects In > Matrix` from IB's menu.

Comment: How did I miss that.. *thumps forhead*

Comment: Happens to the best of us. =)

Comment: Amazing. I spent 3 hours, literally, looking for this simple answer. What haven't I gone reading through… Googling seems to be an art I'm far from mature with. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Yeah, this is NOT as obvious as it should be.